# Java TCP client repetitive connections result in EMFILE error

Tags: java, tcp

My Java application establishes TCP connection with a server and communicates with it every second by sending and receiving messages. Both server and client are run on the same Mac. In about 15-20 minutes, my server crashes with error "Errno::EMFILE Too many files open". Here is my client code:

```
package testtcp;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.EOFException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public class TestTCP extends  JPanel
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Button Demo");

    ScheduledExecutorService executorService;

    private Socket socket = null;
    private DataInputStream input = null;
    private DataOutputStream output = null;
    private BufferedReader br = null;

    private boolean isMapUpdating = false;


    public TestTCP() 
    {
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,300));
        frame.add(this);

        JButton b1 = new JButton("BLACK");
        b1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,50));
        b1.setFocusPainted(false); // get rid of border around text
        add(b1);
        b1.addActionListener((java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) -> 
        {
            startAcarsConnection();
        });

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }


    public void startAcarsConnection()
    {
        start();

    }

    public void start() 
    {
        System.out.println("THREAD START");

        // Default timer rate
        int timerRate = 1;

        executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

        executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() 
        {
            @Override
            public void run() 
            {
                // Create new TCP connection if the map is not currently updating
                if(isMapUpdating == false)
                {
                    isMapUpdating = true;

                    communicateWithServer();
                }
            }
        }, 0, timerRate, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }


    public void stop() 
    {
        executorService.shutdown();
    }

    public void communicateWithServer()
    {
        // Create a message to the server
        String messageToServer = makeMessageToServer();

        // Connect to the client and receive the response    
        String messageFromServer = connectToClient(messageToServer);

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() ->
        {
            messageReceived(messageFromServer);
        });

    }


    public String connectToClient(String messageToServer)
    {
        String data = "";
        // Message from the server that should terminate TCP connection
        String  terminator = "END_IGOCONNECT_DATA";

        try
        {
            // Create socket and streams
            socket = new Socket("192.168.1.2", 7767);
            input = new DataInputStream( socket.getInputStream());
            output = new DataOutputStream( socket.getOutputStream());

            //Send message to the server
            output.writeBytes(messageToServer);


            System.out.println("MESSAGE TO SERVER FROM CONNECT TO CLIENT: "+messageToServer);


            //Read Response
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String s = "";
            int value;

            // Process the message from the server and add to the StringBuilder
            while((value = br.read()) != -1) 
            {
                // converts int to character
                char c = (char)value;

                sb.append(c);

                if(sb.toString().contains(terminator))
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            // Create the final string
            data = sb.toString();
        }

        catch (UnknownHostException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Sock:"+e.getMessage());

            // Close Connection
            cancelConnection();

            // Pop-up message that the airport was not found
            String message = "Application was not able to establish connection with X-Plane.\n"
                    + "Check whether IP Address and Port number were correctly entered in Settings.\n"
                    + "Check whether connection is not being blocked by your firewall.";
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), message, "TCP Connection Error: UnknownHostException",
            JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

            data = "ERROR";
        }

        catch (EOFException e)
        {
            System.out.println("EOF:"+e.getMessage()); 

            // Close Connection
            cancelConnection();

            // Pop-up message that the airport was not found
            String message = "Application was not able to establish connection with X-Plane.\n"
                    + "Check whether IP Address and Port number were correctly entered in Settings.\n"
                    + "Check whether connection is not being blocked by your firewall.";
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), message, "TCP Connection Error: EOFException",
            JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

            data = "ERROR";
        }

        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("IO:"+e.getMessage());

            // Close Connection
            cancelConnection();

            // Pop-up message that the server was not found
            if(!e.getMessage().equals("Socket closed"))
            {
                String message = "Application was not able to establish connection with X-Plane.\n"
                    + "Check whether IP Address and Port number were correctly entered in Settings.\n"
                    + "Check whether connection is not being blocked by your firewall.";
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), message, "TCP Connection Error: IOException",
                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
            // "Connection reset"

            data = "ERROR";
        }

        finally 
        {
            // TO DO!!! DISABLED FOR NOW!! closeSocketPax();
        }

        return data;
    } 


    public void cancelConnection()
    {

        executorService.shutdown();

        closeSocketPax();

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() ->
        {
            System.out.println("Cancel Connection");
        });
    }


    private void closeSocketPax()
    {
        try
        {   
            if(socket!=null) { socket.close();}
            if(input != null) { input.close();}
            if(output != null) { output.close();}
            if(br != null) { br.close();}
        }
        catch (IOException ex) 
        {
            String message = "Error closing socket.";
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), message, "TCP Connection Error: IOException",
            JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
        socket = null;
        input = null;
        output = null;
        br = null;
    }

    private String makeMessageToServer()
    {
        return "MESSAGE TO SERVER";
    }

    private void messageReceived(String message)
    {
        System.out.println("MESSAGE RECEIVED: "+message);

        isMapUpdating = false;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {    
       new TestTCP();
   }
}
```

I have been trying to solve this for almost a month already!
Does anyone see a problem in the code and know how to mitigate the problem? Greatly appreciated!

Comment: Too many files open means you're not closing connections correctly.  Why does your `finally` block not close the connections?

Comment: Thanks, stdunbar. I do not want to close the connection. I want to have it communicate with the server for some time (up to several hours). If I close the connection, I will have to open it every second, correct?

Comment: But you're creating a new Socket - you either need to reuse the Socket or close it.

Comment: I see! I will try to create a new Socket in `start()`. I will report if this solves the issue. Many thanks!

Comment: Thanks, stdunbar. It is working now. You may post your suggestion as an answer to upvote!

Comment: Your `connectToClient)` is misnamed. It should be `connectToServer()`.

Comment: Good catch! Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each connection you create uses a file descriptor.  In any operating system there is a limit to the number of descriptors your process can have. For example, in the Linux environment I'm on the limit is 1024.  Different O/S's have different limits but in Unix derived environments like Linux and Mac O/S you can run `ulimit -n` to see what the limit is.

In your code you do:

```
socket = new Socket("192.168.1.2", 7767);
```

in the `connectToClient` method.  Each time you do that and you don't close the socket you use up a file descriptor.  Eventually you reach the O/S defined limit and you get, in Mac O/S the `Errno::EMFILE` error.

You have two choices to fix this.  The first is pretty much what you have commented out - close the connection when you're done with it.  However, as you indicate in the comments this is occurring very frequently and you don't want to incur the overhead of opening and closing constantly.

That brings us to the second choice - reuse the connection.  A socket can send data over and over again if the protocol you're designing handles it.  Send the data back and forth over the protocol and reuse the Socket.

A warning though - if your physical connection is somehow severed - for example, you switch from Ethernet to Wi-Fi - your service will still need to deal with possible errors.  Your code has most of that but you may want to consider closing and attempting to reconnect when this occurs.